# If Then Statements In One Excel Cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I would like to modify the percentage that is being calculated each time the price changes.

For example the equation is `=+(E25 * G50)/12`, however now I want the calculation to change in the same cell, but this time I want to multiply the figure in cell `G51`. I tried using an `IF` statement: `IF(E25 >=200000 , E25 * G50)/12`, I am probably doing something wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just looking at [how the IF statement works in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), this should do the trick

`IF(E25 >=200000 , E25 * G51, E25*G50)/12`

Comment: Do note that the separator (comma `,`) is language specific. In some languages you need a `;` (semicolon)